# Intersect ERROR:Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Why A get this error: Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed When I Put:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal WS As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim NTT As Range
Set WS = ActiveSheet
Set NTT = WS.Range("$A$1:$U$154")

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("NTT")) Is Nothing Then     '< error Here
```

But Not When I Put

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal WS As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim NTT As Range
Set WS = ActiveSheet

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A$1:$U$154")) Is Nothing Then
```

Unhappily Further in a code I need to use  this format : Range("Name")

Comment: Possible migration candidate to SO.

Comment: @Chrismas007 it's perfectly on-topic here

Comment: @Chrismas007 if you'd like to challenge it, please [do it in meta](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/9099/please-dont-vote-to-close-excel-questions-as-off-topic?cb=1).

Comment: @Raystafarian OK [Here you go](http://meta.superuser.com/a/9101/395086)  All the commenters seem to agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the **Range Object** rather than a *String*

```
Dim WS As Worksheet, NTT As Range
Set WS = ActiveSheet
Set NTT = WS.Range("$A$1:$U$154")
If Not Intersect(Target, NTT) Is Nothing Then............
```

You were very close!